# how can we remove the blurry effect that has been caused by denoising?

Tags: rendering, denoise

(using blender2.82)
hey guys i have been trying to add fog to my scene but when i do it i have a lot of noise in the image i tried to use  blender default denoise but it made it worst because it added huge amount of blur in place of the noise i also tried to use intel AI denoiser but it did the same thing it didn't help
here are the examples:
here with no fog or denoise[image]

and here with fog without denoiser:
[image]

and finally here with denoising:
[image]

how you see the grass get so smooth in bad way!! can any one help? i just want the noise gone without effecting the other objects !

Comment: What method are you using to denoise?

Comment: it is the same result with the INTEL AI denoiser and blender default version

Comment: but if you mean the last image i used the AI version

Comment: so the compositor node?

Comment: @AllenSimpson yes i used the compisitor node

Comment: use more samples and avoid denoising.

Comment: In the case of fog, if you can get away with adding it in compositing - using the [mist pass](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/world_settings.html) is one way - instead of brute-forcing it with volumetric calculations, it should save a lot of time. Of course whether this is practical or not depends on the scene, but the example in your question looks like something I would tackle in compositing. I realize your question is not new, but I mention this for people's future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denoisers are an imperfect, but useful tool.

I have this scene where there's light coming in through a window and I've given the room a volume to catch the light.  If we run a low amount of samples you can see the fireflies produced.

[image]

This is normal, the nature of a volume with lower density is that it will only affect some rays cast from the camera.  The denoiser gives us this ugly result:

[image]

with only little wisps of dust visible.  This is also normal, because the denoiser can only work with the information we give it.  I only ran this at 12 samples, and it is really interesting that it can produce this result.

Usually the answer is to run more samples, but even at 300 samples it comes out as this:

[image]

Which is part of the way there.  I cranked a small region up to 1200 samples to turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

That's a lot of samples, but you can probably see from the noisy image that it would take many thousands of samples to render this volume in a realistic and pleasing way.  Volumes with lesser density are just very noisy.  The grass will be a lesser case of this, where more samples will give each pixel more influence over itself.

I did find in doing this that volumes aren't contributing to denoising normal or albedo, probably by design, but I wonder if it isn't related.

[image]

You may want to play with Adaptive Sampling instead, run some experiments with a render region.

Comment: thanks for the answer :)

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please consider to accept and up-vote it @LightKnight How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour